# Using PHP variables in your CSS file in Symfony

Tags: php, css, symfony1, dynamic-css

I'd love to use PHP variables in my CSS files but I don't want to load up the whole Symfony stack for each file load. Any one have any best practices and/or plugins to manage their CSS files in Symfony?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

but you dont need full symfony stack for that ( except if you need some internal symfony state / variable ).

You just use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/css/mycss.php" />
```

and then you can use php inside your css. you could add appropriate headers (text/css) with header in php.

Comment: i was assuming the .htaccess and routing would try to run the symfony stack but you're right, it'll just hit whatever file is in there. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one good Plugin that tries to manage and/or combine your assets:

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfCombinePlugin

Here's their description:

> Combines multiple JavaScript and CSS
>   files into one JavaScript and one CSS
>   file at runtime, in order to minimize
>   the number of HTTP requests required
>   to render a given page. This plugin
>   works in distributed environments,
>   supports asset version keys, and is
>   highly customizable.

Also, since it's compiled, you *may* be able to use simple PHP as long as the variables stick within the same file.